# How to upload csv file to Dash for creating Network Graphs?

Tags: python, graph, plotly-dash

I want to create Network Graphs Dynamically using Dash-Cytoscape. I tried to import csv file and call it for my graph. Uploading is OK but graph doesn't create. I have one python file. I tried to use [this question][1]. It was helpfully. I can upload a csv file. But i couldn't create a graph with the uploaded file. It didn't get any error.

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html
import base64
import datetime
import io
import csv
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import json
import pandas as pd
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='mygraph',
        layout={'name': 'preset'},
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '400px'},
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'one', 'label': 'Node 1'}, 'position': {'x': 75, 'y': 75}},
            {'data': {'id': 'two', 'label': 'Node 2'}, 'position': {'x': 200, 'y': 200}},
            {'data': {'source': 'one', 'target': 'two'}}
        ]
    ),
html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])
])

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
            df.to_csv('rr.csv')
            with open('rr.csv') as csvfile:
                labels = []
                mappings = []
                csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                headers = next(csvreader, None)

                next(csvreader)

                for row in csvreader:
                    for i in range(len(row)):

                        labels.append({
                            'data': {'id': row[i], 'label': row[i]}, "classes": headers[i]
                        })

                        if i + 1 < len(row):
                            mappings.append({
                                'data': {'source': row[i], 'target': row[i + 1]}, 'classes': headers[i]
                            })

            with open('bb.json', 'w') as f:
                # indent does the prettify
                json.dump(labels + mappings, f, indent=4)
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            data=df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns]
        ),

        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])


@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```